# SQL - insert real time in a database table

Tags: mysql, real-time

I have a database and i need to create a table and insert in a column or columns the real time.

i will explain what exactly i want so maybe you can help.

I am making a game so i need with the pass of time a user to gain coins.
For example if the real time is 12:00 am i want in 12:15 the users to gain 50 coins (so a variable inside the database will change automatically after the pass of time), then in 12:30 they gain 50 coins etc.
and all that will happen even if they are online or offline. (i want database to work all time!)

Comment: This can't usually be done *inside* the DBMS. But to answer that, we have to know which DBMS you are actually using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL (with wampserver)

Comment: Why is it important that their coin count is updated every 15 minutes even when they're offline?  Why don't you just update while they're online, and when they get online for the first time for the day (or whatever) calculate the time difference between log off and log on and update their coin count based on what they needed to earn in that time period?

Comment: that way other player wont be working with actual players coins count

Comment: The game i am making is inspired by another online internet game i am playing. And it work like this: there are for example 20 users and some of the actions you have to do is to steal coins from them. after the pass of time all users (offline or online) gain coins. the good for those that are online is that they can steal for those that are offline, plus with money are based lot of actions in game (upgrades, by armory , take warriors). So i don't know how, but there  is a way to do it.

Comment: well your solution can be write some script and run it like daemon or server or in cron...

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the current time can always be retrieved by using the expression `NOW()`.

Now suppose you want each player to get coins at a rate of 200 per hour. This happens to be one coin every 18 seconds; that's important because we will use integer arithmetic.

Make yourself a table `user` with these columns in it.  I suppose you can also put other columns it it too.

```
  user_id                INT
  current_coin_balance   INT
  last_autopay           DATETIME
```

Then, every so often, run the following query:

```
  UPDATE user 
    SET current_coin_balance = current_coin_balance +
                          ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,last_autopay, NOW()) / 18),
        last_autopay = NOW()
```

If you wish you can add a `WHERE` clause, to only update some user or users in any given run of the query.  Without the `WHERE` clause the query will handle all the users.

This will work out the number of seconds since the most recent payment and divide by eighteen to get the number of coins. It will then credit the user's balance and record the time when the payment was made.

It doesn't matter how often you run this query for any particular user. You can run it every  time a user's record is touched, or every 15 minutes, or whatever you need.

You can run it as a so-called MySQL event (batch job) if you like.